# Django - Can a POST and GET request be returned in one HttpRequest?

Tags: django, post, get

Can a POST and GET request occur in one HttpRequest?

If so, how do I detect the presence of one or the other?

i.e.

`request.method == 'POST'`

and

`request.method == 'GET'`

cannot both be true simultaneously. (Well I imagine one could do some horrible hackery with definition of == or with redirecting calls to method to a function but ew.)

Comment: A HTTP request is either POST _or_ GET not _and_.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. I was unsure whether the OR in the documentation was truly OR or XOR.

Comment: Except Django will actually allow you to send both POST _and_ GET in the same request.

Try setting your form's action attribute to something like action="dosomething/?var=1" and method="post". You will be able to see data in both the request.GET & request.POST QueryDicts.

Answer (score 6):

You don't return a request but a response. The response do not care if its for `GET` or `POST`, it depends upon your implementation as to what you want to do and respond for those requests.

EDIT for comment:
You can safely use your method of checking type of request, i.e. using `request.method == 'POST'` or `request.method == 'GET`. If you want to double sure check for `request.POST` as well.
e.g.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
    #do POST processing

elif request.method == "GET" and request.GET :
    #do GET processing
```

Comment: You're right, and I've updated the question. How do I tell whether POST is actually present or empty, without calling `if request.POST:`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that one HTTP response (as in the underlying technology) cannot / should not return both POST and GET data. I think this fundamental misunderstanding on my part confused people.